# Firebase Realtime database allow superusers to edit subuser data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to allow Super-users to edit sub-users data in Realtime Database through Android app writen in kotlin. Currently I am allowing only one user with id: "Sv6M~~~~~" to edit all of users data. How to get path in Rules and match it with IDs on list under the Super-user? Currently I hardcoded it in code cause I don't know how to get a path for list and iterate through it in "rules section"?

Od what should be right data structure and approach on this requirements?

Data structure in Realtime Database:

[image]

My rules:

````
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      "$uid":{
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.uid === 'Sv6MhRXwd5SXxC2gZw2FRLS9v2K3'", // Here I would like to match super-user with list of sub-users which he has
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.uid === 'Sv6MhRXwd5SXxC2gZw2FRLS9v2K3'"
      }
    },
        "users": {
      "$uid":{
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
} ```
````

Comment: You can't iterate over anything in security rules as the performance would not be predictable in that case. But I'm not sure your use-case isn't possible, because it's not clear yet why a user is allowed to write products. Can you clarify why a user is or isn't allowed to write products/a product?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Generally, I'd like to supervise a sub-user shopping list. For example kid wants to buy a chips, milk and bread. At some point mom wants to add to this list a coca-cola so she can edit her kid list while kid is in the shop. At same point she can supervise few kids so there is relationship one to many so thats why I was thinking about list. Maybe is the other way to give a permission to read/write on kids app/db?

Comment: The use-case is clear, but I'm having a hard time translating it to the data structure and rules. When should a read/write to `products`/`users` be allowed/rejected?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Only user by himself can edit his ```users``` data in database - so mom can later add her kids. So I think nothing changes in ```users```. In ```products```  you are allowed to read/write if auth.uid is yours uid (thats obvious) and when somebody from ```users``` table has uid of sub-user. But you said before that I can't iterate through list so the structure of data has to be changed. The idea with ```admin``` flag is bad cause there exists a lot of moms which would get access to not their kids data. I have no idea how to refactor/fix this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you think it's even possible to create app like this?

Comment: Sorry, but there's just too much domain knowledge in there, which I can't easily translate to code/JSON/rules. I was hoping somebody else was reading along and that they understood it on a level that allowed a concrete answer. If not, I'd recommend bringing this back to a simpler product-level question. E.g. "Writing `/products/$uid` should only be allowed of `/users/$uid` exists" (I'm making this one up, as I don't understand the real use-case, but it should be something in that format/level of detail/domain knowledge).

Comment: Ok I would go for this but as I undestand it right it won't be possible also cause all data is stored under ```uid``` folder in realtime database. Or I got your answer wrong? Or maybe in my case I should create few inserts in ```users``` table to avoid list with sub-users? Or maybe I should just write whole Backend for this?

@Edit Getting a reference to someones DB via code is safe or should be avoid?